# Setting timezone globally for OpenIndiana Hipster?

Tags: configuration, solaris, timezone, openindiana

What is the correct way of setting the timezone (CentralEuropeanTime... or now rather CET with Daylight Savings Time) on the latest version of OpenIndiana Hipster?

I've tried a changing a few things in **/etc/**, but I'm obviously not doing it right, since my clock remains at Universal-time (UTC).  A similar question (for Solaris?) suggested a command, but this isn't available on OpenIndiana - nor is the package it was supposed to be in.

I got a multi-boot system, so I want to keep the system clock in Universal (UTC), rather than in local-time (CET).

So what *exactly* should I do - where and how?
(I guess the easiest would be to just make, edit or link a file in **/etc**, or something if possible...)

Comment: What files have you tried changing?

Comment: I tried setting **/etc/timezone** - but it's possibly I did it wrong...  I put in the line "Europe/Oslo   *MyHostName*".  I also tried to copy the zone-info file for "Europe/Oslo" to **/etc/localtime**.  I should perhaps note that my LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and my keyboard is set to Norwegian...  The time shown is UTC/GMT - the same as the computer's hardware clock.

Answer (score 1):

System-wide timezone setting is controlled by TZ variable in /etc/default/init.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it'd be the same way as changed in Solaris 11, by using `nlsadm`.

## Look for the timezone:

solaris11 [8]#  `nlsadm list-timezone | grep -i central`

Canada/Central

US/Central

I didn't see European central, but there were 62 to pick from if I grep'd for Europe. Your distro of OpenIndiana would probably give different results.

## Set the timezone:

solaris11 [9]#  `nlsadm set-timezone <TIME_ZONE>`

## Update per @Baard Kopperud's comment:

Ok, how about looking to see if the timezone service is in SMF.  As I think nlsadm is a tool to allow the SAs to easily move over from flatfile configs to things being more defined in SMF with v11.

[] #  `svccfg -s svc:/system/timezone:default listprop |grep  localtime`
timezone/localtime                astring     US/Eastern
sysconfig/config_properties       astring     sc_timezone:timezone/localtime`

[] # `svccfg -s timezone:default`
svc:/system/timezone:default> `setprop timezone/localtime = <NEW_TIMEZONE_LOCALE>`
svc:/system/timezone:default> `end`
[] # `svcadm refresh timezone`

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the other post I found suggested...  Unfortunately, there is no `nlsadm` command on my system (only one called `nlsadmin` - which appears to do something completely different).  The other post suggested that the package with the `nlsadm`-command could be installed... I tried, but it appear there is no such package on OpenIndian Hipster.  Hence, I'm trying to find some config-file to edit manually...

Comment: I added an update in regards to your comment.  Not what you're wanting, but you could always specify the TZ in the various shell files (.cshrc, .profile).